# Fastlane, can you perform loops or iterations within your fastfile?

Tags: fastlane

Can you perform loops or iterate (over devices and languages) within the fastlane fastfile or lanes?

I need to do something before and after each the simulator launches / ends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use any Ruby command in a fastlane lane.

So for example:

```
lane :print_images do
   images = Dir[File.dirname(some_search_path) + '/*.png']
   images.each do |image|
       UI.message("found image at: #{image}")
   end
end
```